# Neo4jClient: add arbitrary HTTP headers to Cypher requests?

Tags: http-headers, neo4jclient

I'm trying to add a custom HTTP header to Neo4jClient's outgoing Cypher requests, on a per-request basis. What I mean by per-request basis is that the contents of the HTTP header depend on the (user in the) current session.

The idea is that this header will be interpreted by a load balancer so that it always redirects the request to that slave in the Neo4j cluster where the data of the user in the current session is already mapped to memory, leading to performance gains.

For example, I might keep the address of a particular slave in the user's session and add the HTTP header `Neo4j-slave: <address>` to outgoing requests towards the load balancer. It will then redirect this request to the right slave.

I'm not sure if Neo4jClient is built with this kind of extensibility in mind; from the looks of it, I'm going to have to duplicate a lot of code in non-virtual methods if I don't want to alter existing code.

I've been looking at implementing `IHttpClient` as an entry point into the `GraphClient`. After all, I can pass my implementation to `GraphClient`'s constructor and it receives the outgoing `HttpRequestMessage` so I can modify it along the way) but I think that only works for modifications that only depend on the `HttpRequestMessage` itself (or on some state somewhere but I want to avoid that).

I've also been looking into `ThreadLocal`s as a means to pass additional arguments to `HttpClient#SendAsync` but I'm not sure if those even work if asynchronous methods are involved.

Is there a more or less trivial way to hook into Neo4jClient and add this header?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a good way to do this currently, however if you add the required extensibility to `IGraphClient` in a clean way, I'd accept a pull request for this and we can include it in the published library.